# How can I test my SSO connection without having access to the Identity Provider?

Tags: authentication, sso, saml

I'm trying to set up an SSO connection using [Auth0](http://auth0.com). My app is set up as the Service Provider (SP), and it needs to work with PingFederate as the Identity Provider (IdP).

I don't have access to an account with the IdP, but I want to test that I've got everything on my connection set up correctly - how can I do that **without** installing and setting up a PingFederate server?

Comment: Have you contacted the IdP to see if they can give you a test account? That seems the best option.

Comment: I agree with Neil... most of our customers have at least one non-production environment that they can configure a test connection on for you. I'll say that we have had no issues in the past with Auh0 that I'm aware of.

Comment: I wasn't able to get a test account from the IdP, so in the end we just had a few volunteers on their side to test ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used the service [SSO Circle](http://www.ssocircle.com/en/) which is a freemium public IdP service that you can use to test your connection. It provides metadata, certificates, the whole shebang.

There seems to be a concurrent session limit for the free account and you don't get any error logging/deebugging tools (and the interface is a bit naff) but its certainly better than not having an IdP to test with!